# Start sonar on debian 8

Tags: installation, sonarqube

I have SonarQube 5.6.3 on a debian 8 VM and I want to start sonar with this command : `sonar.sh start` but it shows me this message : `bash: sonar.sh: command not found`. Can you tell me why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

For `sonar.sh start` to work, the current directory or `.` would have to be in your `PATH`. Try like this instead:

```
./sonar.sh start
```

This way Bash will know to execute the script in the current directory (hence the `./` prefix).

You might need to make the script executable first:

```
chmod +x sonar.sh
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134844/discussion-on-answer-by-janos-start-sonar-on-debian-8).